# 301 redirect for some pages and all other pages

Tags: linux, .htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect, shutdown

I have two websites. Let's say `siteA.com` and  `siteB.com`.
Now I want to add 301 redirect to `siteB.com`.
Some of pages of `siteB.com` need to be redirected to some specific pages on `siteA.com`
All other pages of `siteB.com` neet to redirect to the home page of `siteA.com` including siteB's home page.
My final requirement is no one can access siteB after adding the redirection.
These are two wordpress sites. How can acomplish this with htaccess file or a wordpress plugin?

Comment: Do `siteA.com` and `siteB.com` point to different vHosts/servers?

Comment: Yes. Different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `siteA.com` and `siteB.com` point to different vHosts/servers then you can remove all the existing directives in `siteB.com/.htaccess` and use the simpler mod_alias `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives.

For example:

```
# siteB.com/.htaccess

# Specific redirects
Redirect 301 /foo https://siteA.com/another-foo
Redirect 301 /bar https://siteA.com/another-bar
Redirect 301 /baz https://siteA.com/another-baz

# Redirect everything else to homepage on siteA.com
RedirectMatch 301 ^ https://siteA.com/
```

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

NB: Redirecting everything else to the homepage on the other site will likely be seen as a soft-404 by search engines and isn't particularly helpful for users. It is often preferable to serve a more descriptive 404 instead.

> My final requirement is no one can access siteB after adding the redirection.

Since *everything* is redirected, `siteB.com` is effectively inaccessible.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch